# UNIX: How to change all hidden folders/files to visible in a directory

Tags: unix, hidden, mv

I have a directory with more than 100 hidden folders (.folder) and I want to make them visible (folder). Is there a way to do it with one command instead of doing this for each file separately?
The command I have used so far is

`mv .folder folder`

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked to me:

```
rename 's/\.//;' .*
```

It looks for all files with `.something` and renames to `something`.

Comment: All the answers are correct but this one is the simplest. Thank a lot and sorry that I don't have enough reputation to vote you up.

Comment: Good to read it worked to you, @HarrisGeo! No problem about the upvoting :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to do this but you could do the following three commands

```
ls -a | grep "^\.[^\.]" | sed -e "s/\.\(.*\)$/mv \0 \1/" > mv_hidden
chmod +x mv_hidden
./mv_hidden
rm mv_hidden
```

You might want to check that the list of command produce in the file mv_hidden looks correct by executing

```
less mv_hidden
```

Answer (score 1):

To change all files in the current directory from hidden to non-hidden:

```
for f in .*; do
    if [ "$f" != . -a "$f" != .. ]; then
        mv "$f" "${f:1}"
    fi
done
```